# Extract only bullet points from PDF using R or Python

Tags: python, r, parsing, pdf

I have a fairly simple document (the governmental strategies for the mandate) with titles, normal text and then bullet points (which are the strategies they are looking to implement).

I can read and extract pages or titles from the`.pdf` and convert it to a `.txt`  but I'd like to only keep the text (the whole paragraphs) inside bullet points, which is what I'm interested in. I reckon there's some way to do this as they can be identified by the bullet point itself probably.

Is there a simple enough way to do this in R and/or Python? I'm not familiar with other programming languages or parsing methods.

EDIT: Just quickly converted basic text to HTML (using https://wordtohtml.net) on a page and it seems to turn bullet points to `<li>` which I'm guessing would be easy enough to parse through. Is there a quick-n-easy way to convert the whole 262-page document to HTML keeping the `<li>` format probably in R/python? Or do you know of a PDF-way - preferable as it would be at least one less step to do that - for the my issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the `pdftools` package? It has a `pdf_text` function which should at least get you the raw text. You'll have to see if the output is such that you can strip titles and normal text. Regex might get you there depending on how consistent the format is.

Comment: Great idea. Yes, I got the raw text. Below is an excerpt:

`"(...) passarão a estar inscritas políticas públicas que permitam:\n    •    Inverter a tendência de perda de rendimento das famílias, dos trabalhadores, dos\n         funcionários públicos e dos pensionistas;\n "`

`\n` indicate a new line. Assuming it's perfectly written, what I want is in between `•` and `;\n`, since a sentence leading to bullet points ends in `:\n`.

But when creating the data frame out of it I got 1 line per page. I'll need to subset each bullet point to its own line afterwards.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. You should be able to select strings that match the pattern `•.....;\n` with Regex if you have other strings mixed in

Answer (score 4):

Here's my general approach:

Read in a sample string

```
require(stringr)

string <- "passarão a estar inscritas políticas públicas que permitam:\n • Inverter a tendência de perda de 
rendimento das famílias, dos trabalhadores, dos\n funcionários públicos e dos pensionistas;\n"
```

Split by `\n`

```
#  match semi-colon or colon, then a backslash, then "n". I.E. split by ;\n or :\n
stringList <- unlist(str_split(string, "([;:])\\\n"))
```

Return position of any string that starts with a bullet:

```
matched <- grep("\\\u0095", stringList)
```

Subset to strings that start with bullets:

```
stringList[matched]
```

The weak part of this solution currently is that it relies on bullets being preceded by ";\n" or ":\n". If you just split by "\n" you lose the second part of a bullet whenever it continues onto a second line. Depending on the format of the document, you may have to change the regex around to make sure you split the string appropriately

You could also do the initial split by bullet: `stringList <- unlist(str_split(string, "\\u0095"))` but then you need a rule to define where the bullet ends and plain text begins.

Comment: Your solution seems to work though not completely. In my case `matched <- grep("\\\u0095", stringList)` had to be change to `matched <- grep("\\•", stringList)` to get the desired result. Yours returned a matched of `integer(0)` with `stringList[matched]` of `character(0)`.

Comment: Got it to work in the full text. 262 pages apparently have 1071 bullet points! Now I just have to clean up the text a bit, by removing some `\n`and some other stuff that are in the middle of the text.
Per row output example:
`[1] "    •   Relançar o investimento na Ciência, na Inovação, na Educação, na Formação e na\n        Cultura, devolvendo ao país uma visão de futuro na economia global do século\n        XXI"`

Comment: Just to clarify: though in my comment above after `\n` there's only one space, in my code (after pasting to word and messing around with `nchar()` in `R`) there's actually 8 spaces.