# how to extract text in bullets points

Tags: r, string, text-extraction, information-extraction

I'm new in programming and I have to admit it's being a bit difficult.

I'm trying to extract information from several pdf files. I already have al the information carhged in R and what I need to extract now is in bullets.

Example:

From each document in pdf I have information like that, but the heading is different. The only common points is that the information is in bullets:

```
…This research contains the following information:
•   Red flags detected
•   Specific glossary
•   Documents provided by other units
According to the studies…
```

I only need to extract: *Red flags detected.Specific glossary. Documents provided by other units*

My idea is to create a dataframe which contains a summary of all information from each document.

my code is:

`library(dplyr)`
`library(stringr)`
`library(pdftools)`
`library(stringr)`
`require(pdftools)`
`require(tm)`

`setwd("C:/documents/R_Studio")` #route
`list.files()` #vector for pdf files
`files <- list.files(pattern=".pdf$")`

`ci <- lapply(files, pdf_text)`  #load text from all the files
`length(ci)` #verify the files number
`lapply(ci, length)` #verify page number of each file
`str_extract_all(ci)` # In this part is where I'm having problems. I only need to extract the information in bullets
`test<-unlist(str_split(ci, "([;:])\\\n\n"))` #I've tried with test 2 but I don't know hot to extract the info.

The result is the following:

```
\\n\\nThis reaserch contains the following information:\\n\\n   <U+25CF>   Red flags detected\\n   <U+25CF>   Specific glossary\\n   <U+25CF>   Documents provided by other units"\n\nAccording to the studies...'``
```

Comment: Can you show us an excerpt of one of the PDF files as it is imported including the bullets? Like, if there are bullets on the 3rd page of the first file, look at `ci[[1]][[3]]` and put the bullets and couple lines before and after into the question *as they show up in R*.

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075390/extract-only-bullet-points-from-pdf-using-r-or-python

Comment: @GregorThomas [[3]]
[1] "           COMUNICACIÓN  \n\nFecha      de          la   30.01.2023\ncomunicación\n\n\nIdentificación de los intervinientes en las operaciones / Identification of persons\n(individual and legal entities) involved in the transactions\n\n\n  -   
[2] " Descripción de las operaciones \n\n\nP sent from his\n Italian account to an account in Spain.\n\nThe following red flags were:\n\n   ●   Request for information from the German office\n   ●   Bank fraud recall\n   ●   Weird name users\n   ●   Questionable identity documents provided by the subject\n\

Comment: The text I need to extract for any file is in between • and \n\n, since a sentence leading to bullet points ends in \n\n.

Comment: Thank you @Archeologist the problem I've tried with that code. After excuting `cibullets<-unlist(str_split(ci, "([;:])\\\n\n"))` the bullets text appear preceeded by ``\\n   <U+25CF>` but I can't extract the bullet information using  `matched <- grep("\\\<U+25CF>", cibullets)`

Comment: @JoseDavid please edit the text into your question with proper code formatting - I think it's getting mangled in the comments.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas I have changed my question in order to make it easier. The infomation I would like to have is followed by <U+25CF>